# Несколько NOT LIKE средствами REGEXP

Tags: mysql, sql, регулярные-выражения

Нужно отфильтровать email адреса

Можно сделать типа такого:

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages
WHERE 
  email NOT LIKE '%@ya.ru'
  AND email NOT LIKE '%@google.com'
  AND email NOT LIKE '%@yahoo.com'
```

Вопрос - можно ли такое реализовать с помощью одного REGEXP (NOT REGEXP) и если можно, то стоит ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages
WHERE 
  email NOT REGEXP '@(ya\.ru|google\.com|yahoo\.com)$';
```

[Тест на SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7e0c1/8)

По поводу `"стоит ли?"` - надо сравнивать производительность на ваших данных

Comment: Спасибо большое, а зачем экранировать "@"?  Плюс я бы в конец выражения после скобок добавил бы "$"

Comment: @RostD, да по поводу `@` - это я перестраховался (не был уверен что нет такого специального RegEx символа - сейчас проверил - вроде бы нет такого). В общем подправил в ответе...